# Reading city, town or name under Father in 1910 immigration record?

Tags: palaeography, immigration, russia, historical-gazetteer, 1910s

[image]

This is from the Father column in a document of immigration from 1910. I am trying to discover the name of the town/city/region in Russia they came from.

[image]

Comment: That's certainly hard to read! I'd recommend that you compare at least the capital letter of the word to other, more legible, entries on that and surrounding pages in the record set to see if you can work out what it is. It might be "H", but it could be several others. And welcome to G&FH.SE!

Answer (score 1):

The nearest Russian place I can find that roughly fits is Мешково - Meshkovo (which has been transliterated as Meschkovo in the past).

Alternatively, there is Мішково-Погорілове - Mishkovo-Pohorilove in what is now Ukraine.

There is a reference in the Ellis Island records of a Jusef Nowakowski from Mischawa, which may be a clumsy mistransliteration of the same place.